# how can i solve this addrole problem because i cannot find out how?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i wrote a code i found somewhere on stackOverflow and idk how to fix this error bc whenever someone is joining i get this error and it doesn`t give anyone a role

i tried to change the commands and i tried to ask help but nobody could help me

```
});
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User' + member.user.tag + 'has joined the server!');

    var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'user');
    member.addRole();
});
```

idk how to solve it

```
Useranimeclone#0900has joined the server!
(node:4716) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
    at GuildMember.addRole (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:452:38)
    at CommandoClient.bot.on.member (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\index.js:41:12)
    at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Guild._addMember (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1192:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\matti\Downloads\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:4716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)(node:4716) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: why the java tag?

Comment: Question title isn't to state that you have problem which you can't solve, but to shortly *describe* the problem/error, so people who also face it would be able to find it. Please use [edit] option to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'user');
```

Just change it to that

```
var role = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === 'user');
```

Comment: any tips how i can make a function ?

Comment: I already did it just copy and change on your `var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'user');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log(`User: ${member.user.tag} has joined the server!`); //Logs to console
    var role = member.guild.roles.get('user'); //Grab role from server.
    member.addRole(role); //Define role to add
});
```

You should use **get()** since it can get role by both Name/ID and makes your code cleaner.

I used **Template literal** for logging: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also you didn't define which role to add when you called **addRole** function.